# ubuntu 18-04 freezes every second for a second

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, freeze

My ubuntu freezes for a second every 1 or 2 seconds.

This wasn't happening before, i was using two monitors just fine.

Now it keeps giving these fast freezes. I find out why. It's happening because of my second monitor.

If i turn it off, it stops freezing.

My second monitor is connected via HDMI in my graphics-card and the other is via vga on motherboard.

I already have all drivers installed correctly for nvidia.

[current used nvidia driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnZPN.png)

This is a weird thing to happen.

Have you been through this? How can i find a solution for this?

Comment: What do you see in `/var/log/syslog` or `journalctl -f` ?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli when the second monitor is on journalctl -f prints every second this...

https://imgur.com/a/NQaAX6d .

And when its off, it prints only once the same info from the image. In /var/log/syslog is the same.

Comment: Might be a bad / broken HDMI cable / port … It is recommended to check for that first.

Comment: @Raffa i changed my HDMI cable to a new one, no effect. Its related with nvidia driver. I removed nvidia's driver, so i used one monitor, but i let my second monitor on, it had no video but i let it on to test the freezings. So thats how i figured out its about drivers

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing nvidia drivers.

And selected X.OrgXServer nouveau driver

[image: And selected X.orgXServer nouveau driver]

Before this i've updated ubuntu to 20.04. Waste of time.